# Носит ли системный языковой характер изменение оценочного компонента значения церковнославянизмов в русском языке?

Tags: семантика, славянизмы

В современном русском языке ряд слов и выражений церковно-славянского происхождения поменяли оценочный компонент значения. К их числу относятся, например, такие слова, как ВЕРТЕП, ЗЛАЧНОЕ МЕСТО, ТВАРЬ, ПРОЗЯБАТЬ, ЖРАТЬ.

ВЕРТЕП –

I. «Пещера Рождества, то есть место, в котором, по мнению христиан, родился Иисус Христос» (Википедия):

II. «Убежище преступников, развратников; притон». Я попал в один из вертепов, вроде притона "на бойком месте" в драме Островского. Короленко, История моего современника..» (МАС)

ЗЛАЧНОЕ МЕСТО –

I.«Райские кущи, цветник»(Ср.:«Упокой душу раба твоего в месте злачне, в месте покойне»).

II.«Место, где кутят, развратничают» (МАС).

ТВАРЬ –

I.По «Полному церковно-славянскому словарю священника, магистра Григория Дьяченко (М.: «Терра», 1998): «Мiръ» («от начала твари  сея» - Мф., 24,21  - в древнем Евангелии XII века). Иногда под этим именем в Священном Писании разумеется только человек: «Проповедуйте Евангелие всей твари» (Марк. 16,15).

II. По МАС: 1. устар. и прост. Живое существо.Твари земные. Бессловесные твари (животные). Мы все глядим в Наполеоны; Двуногих тварей миллионы Для нас орудие одно. Пушкин, Евгений Онегин.— Ужа нельзя убивать ---. Он хоть по виду змея, а тварь тихая, безвинная. Чехов, Степь.| в знач. собир.— Он добрый, Николай, — собак любит, мышей и всякую тварь. М. Горький, Мать.2. прост.О подлом, мерзком человеке.— А теперь, Алеша, всю правду чистую тебе одному скажу, чтобы ты видел, какая я тварь! Достоевский, Братья Карамазовы.— Вы думали, что я подлец? продажная тварь? Иуда? Гладков, Энергия. Употребляется как бранное слово. — Вера Никитишна с кем-то бранится: «Тварь! Дрянь этакая! Черт!» Чехов, Женское счастье.

ПРОЗЯБАТЬ –

I. По «Полному церковно-славянскому словарю»: «Произращать, производить, рождать». Прозябание сухого жезла Ааронова прообразовало  спасительную смерть и воскресение  Иисуса Христа.

II. Вести жалкую, бедную или бессодержательную, бесцельную жизнь. Прозябать в нищете, в невежестве. Не живут, а прозябают. || существительное прозябание, -я, ср/ (Толковый словарь русского языка: https://www.vedu.ru/expdic/27164/)

ЖРАТЬ –

I. По «Полному церковно-славянскому словарю» ("жрети») : приносить жертву Богу ( Жрет Агнца крестовидно, глаголя: жрется Агнец Божий»)/

II. По МАС: Есть с жадностью (о животных).
— Лиса приходит теперь каждый день и сидит в кустах. Когда цыплята разбредутся по лесу, она ловит какого-нибудь. И тут же жрет. Казакевич, Осень в дубовых лесах. / Прост. пренебр. О человеке.[Митрич:] А коли, примерно, нет у меня ни шиша, жрать нечего. Л. Толстой, Власть тьмы.Да, дома сейчас обедают. Пашка, положив перед собой книгу, жрет щи и не думает о втором, которое он сейчас получит. Каверин, Неизвестный друг.

Безусловно, применительно к каждому слову может быть выстроена отдельная история семантического развития (например, см. статью Е.Э. БАБАЕВА КТО ЖИВЕТ В ВЕРТЕПЕ, ИЛИОПЫТ ПОСТРОЕНИЯ СЕМАНТИЧЕСКОЙ ИСТОРИИ СЛОВА//ВЯ,1998, №3), или комментарий В.В. Виноградова по поводу выражения "злачное место" (Виноградов В. В. Пушкин и русский литературный язык XIX века // Пушкин родоначальник новой русской литературы: Сб. научно-исслед. работ. М.; Л., 1941, с. 552–553), однако общая тенденция изменения характера оценки налицо.

Чем обусловлена эта семантическая тенденция? Внутренними законами развития языковой системы русского языка или внешними социокультурными факторами?

Comment: «...ряд слов и выражений». Есть примеры выражений церк.-славянского происхождения? И ещё: По какой причине Жрать и Жрети можно на одну доску ставить? Кстати, в словаре Ц-СЯ первого слова нет.

Comment: Действительно, я привел в своей формулировке только одно ц.-сл. выражение: ЗЛАЧНОЕ МЕСТО. Но ряд этот можно продолжить. Например: НИЩИЕ ДУХОМ. Раньше употреблялось в значении: "смиренные, лишенные гордыни люди". Современное значение: "люди с узким кругозором, невысокими интеллектуальными и духовными запросами" (презрит.).  Полагаю, что для постановки вопроса необязательно давать полный список. Теперь о ЖРАТИ-ЖРЕТИ. Цитирую Этимологический словарь Макса Фасмера: ЖРАТЬ жру, нажра́ться, укр. же́рти, жра́ти, жру, блр. жерць, жру, др.-русск. жьрати, жьру, ст.-слав. (ПО)ЖРѢТИ "проглотить".

Comment: Я только о словаре Ц-СЯ Г. Дьяченко говорил, где нет статьи слова ЖРАТЬ и нет параллели ЖРАТИ-ЖРЕТИ из-за различия в этимологии. Нет там и ЗЛАЧНОГО МЕСТА, хотя статья ЗЛАЧНЫЙ имеется.

Comment: Энциклопедия Брокгауза и Ефрона`
"Жертва-умилостивительное или благодарственное приношение Богу ... Этимологически это слово происходит от глагола жрети, ЖРАТЬ, пожирать (отсюда жрец, см.) — как вследствие представления о том, что приносимое в Ж. потребляется божеством, так и вследствие того, что Ж., по освящении ее, потреблялась самими приносящими" ЖРАТЬ здесь дается в одном словарном ряду с «жрети», т.е. воспринимается как слово одного корневого гнезда. У Дьяченко есть ЗЛАЧНИКЪ - сад с цветами. Фразеологизмы здесь не толкуются. Поэтому я процитировал для иллюстрации фрагмент панихиды.
.

Comment: Конечно, ЖРАТЬ стоит в приведенном ряду несколько особняком, так как имеет место быть варьирование церковнославянской основы, но пример этот также может служить иллюстрацией общей семантической тенденции к изменению оценочного компонента значения ц.-сл. слов в русском языке. Кстати, знак оценки может меняться и с "минуса" на "плюс". ПРЕЛЕСТЬ у Дьяченко: "заблуждение, прельщение". В МАС:
1.Очарование, обаяние, внушаемое кем-, чем-л. красивым, приятным. "Есть в светлости осенних вечеров Умильная, таинственная прелесть". Тютчев, Осенний вечер. 2.Привлекательность, привлекательная сторона чего-л.

Comment: И еще один, как мне кажется,  существенный момент: следует различать слова церковно-славянского языка и соотносительные с ними церковнославянизмы, которые являются элементами русского языка.

Comment: Например, какую пару слов можете назвать?

Comment: Иными словами, ЖРѢТИ - элемент церковно-славянского языка, а ЖРАТЬ - соотносительный с ним церковнославянизм, который претерпел существенную оценочно-стилистическую

Comment: Они сильно различны. Зачем их различать, зря напрягаться.

Answer (score 1):

Говорить о системе можно, когда есть какой-то принцип в изменении семантики, здесь же речь идёт о неоднородности старославянизмов в семантическом плане.В их составе выделяются две противопоставленные друг другу группы слов:

1. старославянизмы (церковнославянизмы) с сохранившейся исходной семантикой;
2. семантически трансформированные церковнославянизмы.

Естественно, что славянизмы, семантика которых в русском языке не изменилась (например, влага, изречь, младенец, претвориться), будут употребляться в одних и тех же значениях, как православными, так и неправославными людьми. Семантически трансформированные славянизмы (СТС), в зависимости от мировоззрения говорящего (пишущего),  могут употребляться или только со значениями, присущими им в кодифицированном русском языке, или и с общепринятыми значениями и со значениями, характерными для церковнославянского языка.

Так, у глагола прозябнуть (прозябать) в современном русском языке развилось значение 'вести жалкую или бессодержательную жизнь', например: «Эти женщины не жили никогда, а прозябали только, кормились и хозяйничали» (Помяловский, Молотов). Исходное, церковнославянское значение этого слова — 'произрастать, производить' — отмечено как книжное и устаревшее в МАСе, а в словаре Ожегова–Шведовой этого значения вообще нет, так как авторы словаря не включали в него «старые или устаревшие слова и значения, выпавшие из языка, практически не нужные с точки зрения современного языкового общения, понимания ближайшей исторической действительности или текстов классической литературы…»

Однако в книге К. В. Мочульского «Достоевский. Жизнь и творчество», написанной в 1942 г., мы читаем: «Зерно, умершее в «мертвом доме», прозябло и принесло плод — гениальные романы-трагедии. Каторжный опыт писателя — его духовное богатство». Для Мочульского глагол прозябнуть и его церковнославянское значение не «выпавшие из языка», потому что ему, конечно, была известна притча о сеятеле: «…другое же паде на земли блазе и прозябы, сотвори плоды сторицею» (Лк 8:8).

За 70 лет советской власти связь церковнославянского и русского языка в языковом сознании народа разрушилась. Мировоззрение у большей части людей стало каким угодно , только не православным. Для таких людей гордый человек  — положительное качество, а воскресают у них в первую очередь события прошедшего, мысли, чувства, переживания. Для православных  гордость  — грех. «Из примера св. царя пророка видно, что гордость и самонадеянность вреднее прелюбодейства и убийства», — писал преп. Амвросий Оптинский."Ты, гордый!"по отношению к Ларре в "Старухе Изергиль" Горького тоже имеет отрицательную коннотацию.

В наше время исходные значения у СТС встречаются чаще всего в церковной литературе.

Например, все образованные люди знают, что крестоносец — это 'участник крестового похода'. Как тогда понимать такую фразу: «…народ наш был необычайно терпелив и кроток… Крестоносец народ». Все станет на свои места, если понимать, что слово крестоносец имеет значение 'тот, кто терпеливо переносит посланный от Бога крест'.

Прилагательное благоверный в современном русском языке выступает как шутливо-иронический эпитет одного из супругов: «Добрая, хотя строгая супруга уже обложила своего благоверного сеном и одеждой» (Горький, Ярмарка в Голтве). В церковнославянском языке это слово имеет значение 'исповедующий истинную веру, православный' и является постоянным эпитетом князей, царей, епископов.

У прилагательного блаженный в МАСе отмечаются значения 'в высшей степени счастливый' и 'глуповатый, чудаковатый'.Но его церковнославянское значение — 'святой': «Человек! Какое это высокое имя! — писал **блаженный** о. Иоанн Кронштадтский в дневнике своем».

Явление сохранения исходных значений характерно не только для слов, пришедших в русский язык из церковнославянского, но и для общеславянских слов, значения которых изменились в русском языке, но сохранились в церковнославянском. Так,  существительное тварь употребляется со значением 'создание, творение, живое существо, человек', которое не свойственно современному русскому языку.

Конечно, далеко не все слова с изменившейся семантикой сохраняют свои исходные значения в речи православных носителей русского языка. Да и не каждый верующий знает, какие значения в церковнославянском языке были у слов безвременный, возразить, возмездие, изумиться, изящный, равнодушный, сад, стража, странный, хламида и др. Церковнославянская семантика, в основном, сохраняется и актуализируется тогда, когда это необходимо для отображения православного взгляда на мир (у таких слов, как ангельский, воплотиться, воплощение, воскресение, воскресить, воскреснуть, гордость, ересь, прелесть, смирение и т. п.), например: «Дар Божий — не только сладость жизни, дар Божий — и горечь ее. На Страшном Суде нам придется дать ответ: как мы распорядились этим даром. Разменяли ли мы наши скорби на терпение и смирение или ожесточились сердцем. И, наоборот, от удач и счастья не сделались ли мы самодовольными и гордыми».

Так что обусловлена эта семантическая тенденция, как Вы сказали, **внешними социокультурными факторами**

http://refdb.ru/look/2436355-p27.html

Answer (score 1):

Сначала три цитаты.

Церковнославянский язык никогда не был вполне понятен и всегда отличался от разговорного — даже в эпоху святых Кирилла и Мефодия, которые, воспользовавшись разговорным языком, создали на его основе новый — богослужебный, или литургический язык.
«Непонятность» церковнославянского языка объясняется не столько свойствами самого этого языка, сколько неподготовленностью людей, лишённых на протяжении многих лет возможности серьёзно и глубоко изучать богослужение. / Еп. Иларион (Алфеев).

Церковнославянский язык — в общем-то, язык искусственный: он был создан для перевода сложных, изощренных сочинений на устный племенной язык, который ещё не выработал словаря для важнейших отвлеченных и богословских понятий. / Ольга Седакова.

Церковнославянский язык — постоянный источник для понимания русского языка. Сохранения его словарного запаса, обострённого постижения эмоционального звучания русского слова. Это язык благородной культуры: в нём нет грязных слов, на нем нельзя говорить в грубом тоне, браниться. Это язык, который предполагает определённый уровень нравственной культуры. Церковнославянский язык, таким образом, имеет значение не только для понимания русской духовной культуры, но и большое образовательное и воспитательное значение. Отказ от употребления его в Церкви, изучения в школе приведет к дальнейшему падению культуры в России. / Д.С. Лихачев.

Если в обратном порядке: церковнославянский — кристальной чистоты язык, искусственный эталон — от племенных языков и для них же сотворённый — и со времён своего создания Кириллом и Мефодия  **в с е г д а**  не вполне понятный народу. И наиболее вероятно, что переоценку значения многих бытовавших слов первыми справили его создатели, а процесс объединения или расхождения смыслов в одной форме слова пошёл сразу же и по закону жанра должен бы завершиться, если не завершился уже. Будет расти во времени, не имея прямого отношения к ЦСЯ, лишь ряд синонимов.